# PHP or JS redirect to another page with reloading and url changing

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, reload

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but no solution worked for me.

I have index.php with a login form. When a user tries to login, then the login-datas are send to login.php this file checks if the username and password are valid. 
If so, the file map.php shell be loaded.
The only working solution I found for this is: 
    header("Location: map.php");
But when the page is loaded the url is still ../login.php how can I change this?

Another problem is, if I go from pageB.php to pageA.php, doing some database changes, then redirecting from pageA.php back to pageB.php with header("Location: pageB.php"); then pageB.php is loading, but doesn't show the changed database entries, just the old ones. How can I force to reload the page for just ONE time (means no Refresh:X)?

Comment: Hmm PHP header should change the URL. Are you sure that you are directed to map.php for real?

Comment: For your next question, try to add to pageB.php: header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes I'm sure to be correctly directed to map.php, but the url doesn't change and is still login.php.

Comment: I already tried some chache options:
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
and also yours now, but nothing changed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check if PHP us using a cache, like OpCache or something.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit confusing but the best way to handle client redirection is using Javascript rather than the headers being sent back from PHP unless you are redirecting due to a 404, 403 etc.

For the login use case when the client provides their info fire off an ajax post event containing the form data. Process the data using PHP and send back a response to the Javascript. Based on the return message from PHP use the window.location API to redirect / refresh as needed.

Comment: Why is this better than a `Location` header?

Comment: Because headers wont work for with AJAX calls if the OP decides to go that route at a later date. Change the response headers when an Asynchronous request is made cannot redirect / refresh the client. For future compatibility it would be better to handle client redirect from the client itself and let PHP worry about processing the data and authenticating instead.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP requests a solution for redirect / refresh using either PHP or JS.

Comment: If you're going to change from "regular" to AJAX request, you're going to have to change more than just a header. These two warrant entirely different responses. Sounds like a pretty weird reason. You either use one or the other for a number of reasons; using AJAX because you'd have to change stuff if you'd change to AJAX later is not one of them.

Comment: I am not saying that by changing the header you will be able to make an AJAX request. My point is that if you are going to solve the problem, solve it the way that offers you the most options in the future. If you architect the solution to rely on the server side code to handle redirection based on the headers you have painted yourself into a corner. Since the OP mentioned wanting a solution in either PHP or JS this solution will give them the most options later down the road with the least code refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to prevent AJAX, because I'm not really used to it.
And I already tried the window.location API, but it didn't work for my problem.